# Rotation and getBounds() in Phaser

Tags: rotation, sprite, bounds, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser 2.3.0 and I want to know the bounds of a rotated sprite.

But when I change **sprite.rotation**, the values of **sprite.getBounds()** don't change:

```
sprite = game.add.sprite(0, 0, "img"); // game.load.spritesheet("img", "grid.png", 32, 32);
console.log(sprite.getBounds()); // Object { x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32, type: 22 }
sprite.rotation = 0.52; // 30°
console.log(sprite.getBounds()); // Object { x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32, type: 22 }
```

What's wrong?

How can I get the correct bounds?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, `getBounds()` will return the smallest possible rectangle that the object fits in and since `Phaser.Rectangle` doesn't have a rotation property, you will get the same rectangle both times.

Answer (score 0):

It's being 6 years since this question, but just for the people who end up here after a Google search, the right answer is that the `getBounds()` is based on the object's `worldTransform` which is updated at the end of the `render()` cycle. So changing something in the object and in the next line trying to get its bounds will give you the old value. The solution is to wait a frame or call `updateTransform()`:

```js
const sprite = game.add.sprite(0, 0, "img");
console.log(sprite.getBounds());
// Phaser.Rectangle { x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32, type: 22 }

sprite.rotation = 0.52; // 30°
sprite.updateTransform();
console.log(sprite.getBounds());
// Phaser.Rectangle {x: -15.900164410999576, y: 0, width: 43.67037816068437, height: 43.67037816068437, type: 22}
```

https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Sprite.html#getBounds

Keep in mind that if the object is inside an hierarchy of objects, you should call `updateTransform()` in the highest object.